# Pagination in Android

Tags: android, listview, pagination

I am

- writing an app to attend a quiz.
- obtaining the questions from a json.
- able to populate the questions along with the options using a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter.

**Problem**

As the list goes bigger, it is difficult to answer. What I want is each question to be displayed in one layout. When the user clicks on next it should load the next question.

QuizView.java

```
List<Quiz> quizList = new ArrayList<Quiz>();

    String json = "[{\"question\": \"What?\", \"option1\": \"alpha\" , \"option2\": \"beta\" , \"option3\": \"gamma\" , \"option4\": \"alpha\"},{\"question\": \"What?\", \"option1\": \"alpha\" , \"option2\": \"beta\" , \"option3\": \"gamma\" , \"option4\": \"alpha\"}]";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

    for(JsonElement obj : array) {
    Quiz quiz = gson.fromJson(obj,Quiz.class);
    String question = quiz.getQuestion();
    System.out.println("Question: "+question);
    quizList.add(quiz);
```

Quiz.java

```
public class Quiz {

    public String question;

    public String option1;
    public String option2;
    public String option3;
    public String option4;

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setOption1(String option1) {
        this.option1 = option1;
    }

    public String getOption1() {
        return option1;
    }

    public void setOption2(String option2) {
        this.option2 = option2;
    }

    public String getOption2() {
        return option2;
    }

    public void setOption3(String option3) {
        this.option3 = option3;
    }

    public String getOption3() {
        return option3;
    }

    public void setOption4(String option4) {
        this.option4 = option4;
    }

    public String getOption4() {
        return option4;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/  
I found the solution for this problem at the above site. Thank you !!!